# Trigger to update a value in same table when another is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new to the SQL larg, and learning my way through it.

I need to be able to update a value in a table when anther value in the same row is edited.

I currently have this.

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[distval1]    Script Date: 03/12/2018 13:22:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create TRIGGER [dbo].[distval3]
ON [dbo].[ZID00181]
AFTER INSERT  
AS 
BEGIN



IF UPDATE(supplier_code) 
  begin

update ZID00181
  set Distribution_Value = '200'
  where Supplier_Code like '2%'


  --set Distribution_Value = branch_plant 
  --where supplier_code like '4%'

  end

END
```

so basically when teh supplier code begins with a 2 it sets distribution value.

That seems t work fine when first imported, but if it gets imported with a null and then later updated it doesnt work.

ANy ideas?

Comment: You probably want to do `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` instead of `AFTER INSERT`

Comment: But why not make this column (Distribution_Value) a computed column? Then you never need to update it separately from Supplier_Code. This really looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - now might be a good time to rethink your design.

Comment: Thank you, but im not sure the application updating the value spports computed columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your trigger as "AFTER INSERT,UPDATE".
Also I believe you want to do update "Distribution_Value" only if supplier_code change in same row. So, your update works for entire table which match with Supplier_Code like '2%'. If you want to update only the row that updated you need to do something like that :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[distval3]
ON [dbo].[ZID00181]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

IF UPDATE(supplier_code) 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE ZID00181
      SET Distribution_Value = '200'
      WHERE Supplier_Code like '2%'
      AND ZID00181.<PRIMARY KEY HERE> IN (SELECT <PRIMARY KEY HERE> FROM INSERTED)
      --set Distribution_Value = branch_plant 
      --where supplier_code like '4%'
  END
END
```